# Extend Url Route to apply Url Encoding for each parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I am facing a problem that one of my fields need to be shown in the url contains special character (/, \, :).

The stupid way to handle this generate action links by using UrlEncode(). Then UrlDecode is used before consuming in controller. But I think it really stupid because too many places need to be adapted.

So, my problem is there any way to extend the url route or just write my own one to achieve it?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the `System.Web.Routing.Route` object to create a custom route and override the  `GetRouteData` and `GetVirtualPath` methods. These are called to resolve a route's values and create a URL from given route values, respectively. However, I don't think URLs can contain URL encoded values for / (%2f) within the path portion of a URL though it is ok in a query string.

Comment: The route's constructor requires a IRoutHandler, how do you supply that?